# Convergent series similar to $(\csc(x))^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I have this series
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{x+n}{|x+n|^3}$$

Which seemed quite similar to that of $(\csc(x))^2$:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+πn)^2}$$

The only difference is the change of sign throughout the sum, does this series also converge to some function?